# How full does a home water heater get?

Tags: water-heater

It's about time to replace my anode rod in my 40 gallon water heater. I am interested in trying one of these actively powered models: [https://www.amazon.com/Corro-Protec-CP-R-Titanium-Powered-Heater/dp/B01H459TAK/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01H459TAK)

because if the advert is true, this should take care of corrosion "forever", well at least with a 20 year warranty.

The major difference between this one and a standard noble-metal version, other than the fact that it's powered and made of titanium, is how short of a rod this one has. I'm assuming the rod needs to be somewhat submerged to have an effect.

How full does a home water heater usually stay? Is there a high/low water-level threshold used to determine when to control more water, or is it a continual refill?

Comment: Why do you think it is time time replace the original anode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A water heater stays 100% full all of the time due to the fact replacement cold water (to be heated) is being added via the cold water inlet line at the top of the water heater each time a hot water tap is opened.

Comment: Because of the dip tube, water is however added at the bottom of the tank.

Comment: Tyson is correct. Water heaters normally bring the cold water into the tank at the bottom and remove hot water from the top. But NETXMusician is correct that the tank stays completely full.

Comment: OA didn't say the cold water entered the top of the tank, but rather, said the inlet line is at the top of the *heater*.

Answer (score 1):

Let me speak to the changing of an anode rod.  I would agree that depending upon the water quality in your area, the rod may need to be changed a couple of times over the life of the tank.  Regarding the fullness of the tank, it is indeed 100% full all the time.  If you are concerned about the spillage of water in he process of pulling the old rod, once you shut the water off to the tank, just open a hot water faucet some where in the house lower than the top of the tank for a minute. Minimal water spillage; minimal cleanup.

Now to the difficult part.  The manufacturers of these tanks for some reason are just sure that there is a very good chance of water leakage around the connecting threads of the anode rod itself. The rods are installed with such force that it is at a minimum a two man job to remove them.  And even with two experienced men, it can be very difficult. Forewarned is Forearmed.